# Update query in a trigger

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I have a configuration table:

Table: `refdatecol`

```
id           int(11)
startdatecol varchar(100)
enddatecol   varchar(100)
datecolTable varchar(100)
```

This table holds the user configured **column names and table names**. 
I am building a query run time using the data from `refdatecol` and updating another table `project_wbs`. I am using dynamic SQL.
This works fine inside the procedure.

Problem is: I want to fetch the current date values into the `project_wbs` on *insert* OR *update*. Naturally, I thought of using trigger. But triggers do not support dynamic SQL in MySQL.

So I thought of calling the procedure from the trigger. Then I learnt it is a strictly no-no.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

I am also open to considering a complete redesign of this *user-configurable dates*

**Update**

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create  procedure sp_project_date (_id int)
begin

set @_startdate ='';
set @_enddate ='';
set @_projectId = (select project_wbs.proj_projectId 
                   from   project_wbs project_wbs 
                   where  id = _id);

set @q = (select concat('select ', startdatecol, ' , ', enddatecol ,
                        ' into @_startdate, @_enddate  from ' , datecolTable , 
                        ' where project_ProjectId = ' , @_projectId) as 'query' 
          from refdatecol
          where id = (select p.cogsDateId 
                      from   project p 
                      where  p.projectId = @_projectId)
          );

prepare stmt from @q;
execute stmt;

UPDATE project_wbs 
SET    project_startdate = @_startdate, 
       project_enddate = @_enddate 
WHERE  id = _id;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Do you have the trigger code as well ???

Comment: Not really. I thought of creating a trigger and when I researched about it, I came to know about this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10657/35206 . Hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use some user defined variables. I once wrote an answer to this : [Disable trigger for just one table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11046/disable-trigger-for-just-one-table/11055#11055). I suggested setting up a user defined variable to disable a trigger.

In your case, dynamic SQL is not necessary if you are simply changing parameter values for a SQL statement. If you are changing table names and column names for the query, you got to construct some [good `IF...THEN` blocks in the trigger like my post demonstrates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11046/disable-trigger-for-just-one-table/11055#11055). If there are too many tables or too many column names to make `IF...THEN` blocks, then stick with the Stored Procedure approach.

Comment: Using if..then in the trigger is a very nice idea. I will have to check if it is feasible for my situation. As of now there are not many combinations, but the business user suspects it might grow in future. What would you suggest in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Use your dynamic SQL and/or stored procedure to insert your records in `project_wbs`.

Add one or more triggers to `project_wbs` `on update` and/or `on insert`. Within the trigger, set the `project_wbs.Current_Date_Column_Name` value to `now()`.

That is all.

Your dynamic SQL / stored procedure takes care of updating the business data and your trigger takes care *only* of updating the "current date / time" column in that table - any time the record is inserted/updated (whatever meets your requirements).

Note - this will update the column when *any* SQL updates your data in `project_wbs`. Is this acceptable?

There is [some simple SQL in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138928/mysql-set-current-date-in-a-datetime-field-on-insert) on stack exchange that shows you how to construct the trigger (assuming no other logic than to set the current time on any/every update/insert).